# Integration which includes a diffferential(infinitesimal?) element of combined function , not a kind of $~ dx, d\theta ,ds,dt ~$

Tags: integration, systems-of-equations, infinitesimals

I think that this is the first wime when I handle an integration with infinitesimal(differetial?) element with combined function .

$$  a \in \mathbb R_{> 0} $$

$$  \int_{0 }^{\frac{\pi}{2}  } \frac{  1  }{  a ^{2} + \tan^{2}\left( x \right)   }  \,d \left( \tan^{}\left( x \right)  \right)    $$

I've done the below transformations .

$$  \int_{0 }^{\frac{\pi}{2}  } \frac{  1  }{  a ^{2} + \tan^{2}\left( x \right)   }  \,d \left( \tan^{}\left( x \right)  \right)    $$

$$ = \left( \frac{  \frac{  a  }{  a  }   }{   \frac{  1  }{  1  }  }  \right) \int_{0 }^{\frac{\pi}{2}  } \frac{  1  }{  a ^{2} + \tan^{2}\left( x \right)   }  \,d \left( \tan^{}\left( x \right)  \right)    $$

$$ = \left( \frac{  \frac{  1  }{  a  }   }{   \frac{  1  }{  1  }  }  \right) \int_{0 }^{\frac{\pi}{2}  } \frac{  a }{  a ^{2} + \tan^{2}\left( x \right)   }  \,d \left( \tan^{}\left( x \right)  \right)    $$

$$ = \frac{1}{ a }  \int_{0 }^{\frac{\pi}{2}  } \frac{  a }{  a ^{2} + \tan^{2}\left( x \right)   }  \,d \left( \tan^{}\left( x \right)  \right)  $$

$$ = \frac{1}{ a } \left[ \tan^{-1} \left( \frac{  \tan^{}\left( x \right)   }{  a  }  \right)   \right]_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2} }  $$

$$ = \frac{ \pi    }{  2a  }  $$

Currently I can't get why this integration is correct .

First things to first , can I assume that the values of $~ d \left( \tan^{}\left( x_{} \right)  \right)  ~$ are all same for all $~ x  ~$ in the limit of $~ \left[ 0:\frac{\pi}{2}  \right]  ~$?

Comment: Some authors use $d(f(x))$ as shorthand for $f'(x)dx.$ But you'd have to check text where you got this to see if they do that.

Comment: I've seen this notation used to mean you should make the substitution u = tan x. It's the sort of thing one might write when one is explaining how substitution works. The derivative of tan is $\sec^2$ if memory serves, so if the integrand was originally $\sec^2 x/(a^2 + \tan^2(x))$, then when you do substitution, you would absorb the numerator into the differential. This is just another way of writing that same thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HINT:

Note upper limit of $\tan(x)=u $ set conveniently  has $ \infty$ for the upper limit but not $\pi/2$.

So

$$  \int_{0 }^{\infty  } \frac{  du }{  a ^2 + u^2} = 
\frac{1}{a}\; \tan^{-1}\frac{u}{a}+c $$

and evaluating the two limits:

$$=\frac{1}{a}\; (\tan^{-1}\infty -0)=\frac{\pi}{2a}.$$